# How to echo exactly this string containing of special characters

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write exactly this string into CRON programmatically, but when I do:

```
echo "*/2 * * * * for i in `docker ps -a| grep -v Up | awk '{print $NF}'`; do ~/./check_service.sh $i; done >/dev/null 2>&1" >> mycron
```

I got:

```
neo4j; do ~/./check_service.sh neo4j; done >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So how can I escape all those special characters and prevent the script being executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use single quotes to prevent bash/shell expansion/evaluation.  You also need to escape the single quotes around the `awk` script as below.

```
$ echo '*/2 * * * * for i in `docker ps -a| grep -v Up | awk '\''{print $NF}'\''`; do ~/./check_service.sh $i; done >/dev/null 2>&1' >> mycron
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfect, will accept answer when allowed